# Joomla 3 Как вывести текст в шаблоне на нужной мне страницы средствами php?

Tags: php, joomla

Хочу вывести что-то на определенной странице. Например у меня есть страница "тест" и я хочу на ней вывести какой то div, как сделать проверку?

Если страница "тест", то показать

Answer (score 1):

Собственно решил проблему так

```
<? if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/index.php'){ ?> 
тут бла - бла
<?  } ?>
```

Может кому пригодится